# How do you make a dynamic start page in HTML/JavaScript/MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, start-page

So I'm currently working on a start page (personal use) but right now I have to edit the HTML if I want to add/delete/edit a website or container.

What's the easiest way to make an in-browser experience? I have tried JavaScript and that worked but once you refresh the page it removes the added element.

The startpage is made up of a container of class "**content**" and then individual containers in class "**container**". These containers contain a header and the links to the different pages.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need the server side with some form of persistance (e.g.: database, files). You can use: Nodejs, php, Java, C#, python... almost everything.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a CMS.  Don't remake the wheel.  There's plenty of them out there.

Comment: I suppose a CMS is possible with php?